# Python 3.5 Regular expressions cannot read text file

Tags: python, regex, validation, text-parsing, encase

Would it be a good idea to convert a text file to a doc string (same as literal string) for regular expressions to work?  I've tried converting it to a string with `str()` and using multiline mode in re.

I've created a rudimentary script to parse out an [EnCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EnCase) export file via Python.  It works but for some reason I can't get regular expression code to do a findall function to search the file unless I store the contents of the file as a doc string in a variable as such.

```
file = '''

'''
```

It seems that this code can be reused for different files but it becomes cumbersome to copy and paste every file content.  Any other suggestions?

The EnCase file export is essentially tab delimited and the following has information as to the format of the file.

Also see: [Exporting Files and Folder from EnCase](http://Exporting%20Files%20and%20Folder%20from%20EnCase)

Comment: Please clarify your question. Chances that people know what EnCase files are or how they look like are pretty minimal, bring meaningful samples of your input, your code attempts and most importantly the expected output for those samples.

Comment: I tried pasting the file format on this forum and github but it just strips the tabs and carriage returns out.  Here is what I have https://github.com/jshen9393/data_wrangling/blob/master/encase_example.md

Comment: Take a few minutes to familiarize yourself with how this website works and how markdown works. This is a Q&A site about programming, it is perfectly capable of keeping newlines and tabs, you just did not bother to read the instructions.

Comment: Thanks!  I will review the QA.  Perhaps I made this question too lost in the details as well.  How would one load a text file like a doc string?

Comment: That's a really, really basic question, if that is your actual question. Take a stab at the Python documentation, look around on the Internet. You will find thousands of examples for this.

Comment: I dont know how to call this problem or the solution I have in my mind.  I've tried some of the thousands of solution and doesnt work.  Not sure where to  start looking in documentation.  Thanks

Comment: I did not say "if that is your actual question" without reason. You made that simplification. My first comment above applies.

Comment: I believe this is an encoding issue and this is why I haven't found much articles relating to this topic as I don't believe I'm that ignorant as to not be able to open a file (please dont say if you think otherwise :)).

Comment: No, I would have been surprised. But it really would have helped if you had simply posted your Python code so far instead of being all vague and implicit. Please try to read your next question from the point of view of somebody who has no clue what you are talking about, before you post it, this really saves time for everyone.

Comment: Duly noted.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the file. This will give you a string:

```
In [2]: with open('encase_example.md') as cf:
   ...:     data = cf.read()
   ...:     

In [3]: data[:41]
Out[3]: '\n1)\nName\tfile.doc\nFile Category\tDocument\n'
```

(Just showing part of the string as an example.)

Note in the data that there are newlines between fields of each record, but tabs between the key and value of each field. We will use this later.

This works with regexes:

```
In [14]: re.findall('Full Path.*', data)
Out[14]: 
['Full Path\tproject\\D\\analysis\\system\\folder\\file.doc',
 'Full Path\tproject\\D\\analysis\\system\\folder\\file2.doc']
```

If you want to separate the records, just split on `\n\n`:

```
In [18]: records = data.split('\n\n')

In [19]: len(records)
Out[19]: 2

In [20]: records[0][:50]
Out[20]: '\n1)\nName\tfile.doc\nFile Category\tDocument\nFile Type'
```

You can also make the records into a dictionary:

```
In [35]: dict([ln.split('\t') for ln in records[0].splitlines()][2:])
Out[35]: 
{'Entry Modified': '12/18/14 11:18:53AM',
 'File Acquired': '04/28/15 01:54:45PM',
 'File Category': 'Document',
 'File Created': '03/29/14 03:22:59PM',
 'File Deleted': '',
 'File Type': 'Word Document',
 'Full Path': 'project\\D\\analysis\\system\\folder\\file.doc',
 'Is Deleted': '',
 'Last Written': '08/18/08 01:20:48PM',
 'Name': 'file.doc',
 'Physical Location': '546,930,589,696',
 'Physical Size': '32,768'}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This may not have solved my problem but it gave me a way to diagnose it.  I believe its an encoding issue as I used data[:41] and came up with this:
'ÿþK\x00a\x00r\x00i\x00n\x00a\x00 \x00r\x00e\x00s\x00u\x00l\x00t\x00s\x00 \x00#\x001\x00 \x00f\x00i'
I believe this is some kind of windows encoding and thats why my regex has not been working.  I'll have to start reading about converting it to UTF8.

Comment: @JimmyShen Are you using Python2 or 3?

Comment: 3.5  I believe I have a code that converts the source file to utf-8

import chardet
encoding = 'UTF-8'

with open(file,'rb') as file:
    file = file.read()    
    file_encoding = chardet.detect(file)
    file_encoding = file_encoding['encoding']
    if encoding not in file_encoding:
        print('converting file encoding to utf-8')
        data = file.decode(file_encoding).encode(encoding)
    else:
        print('file encoding is utf-8')
        data = file

data = data.decode(encoding)

Comment: I get the following error when doing the above with a 'utf-16' file:
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte'

It seems like its the equivalent of applying a spanish translation to a french text.  The encoding field seems like it should only be populated when it is not the default encoding and you know it.

Comment: Yes. You should  What is interesting is that the file that I downloaded from your github account wasn't UTF-16 encoded. Have a look at what `import sys; sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns for you. If it's not, UTF-16, then that is probably the cause of your problem. I didn't recognize the BOM (byte order mark) in your comment: `bytes([255, 254]).decode('latin-1') = 'ÿþ'`.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I had found taht it was utf 16 and works now.  Perhaps github changed the format as I just pasted the data in github.  Ill have to use the sys function at a later time as it seems useful.